# How to count the index while matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nsregularexpression

### Goal

I'd like to get words surrounded by specific symbols, such as parentheses and their index numbers.

```
# input and symbol []
A key word is put in parentheses, like these: [keyword] or [key word] 

# output 
keyword (9, 9)
key word (11, 12)
```

Index numbers are considered that follow a list from splitted input sentence.

### Issue

Current output has mainly two problems.

1. Index count is done by not word base.
2. Matching with regular expression didn't work that I expected.

output

```
['A', 'key', 'word', 'is', 'put', 'in', 'parentheses,', 'like', 'these:', '[keyword]', 'or', '[key', 'word]']

keyword] or [key word
(47, 68)
```

### code

```py
import re

sentence = "A key word is put in parentheses, like these: [keyword] or [key word]"
splitted = sentence.split(' ')
matched = re.finditer("(?<=\[).*(?=\])", sentence)
print(matched)
for w in matched:
    print(w.group())
    print(w.span())
```

How can I fix my current code to extract goal output?

Comment: You don't need regex for that. Just ```split()``` the phrase and check if ```[``` in the elements

Comment: use this as the correct pattern: matched = re.finditer("(?<=\[)([a-z ]+)(?=\])", sentence)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
import re

sentence = "A key word is put in parentheses, like these: [keyword] or [key word]"
splitted = sentence.split(' ')
matched = re.finditer("(?<=\[)([a-z ]+)(?=\])", sentence)
#print(matched)
for w in matched:
    start = len(sentence[:w.span()[0]-1].split())
    quantity = len(w.group().split()) - 1
    print(w.group(), (start, start + quantity))
```

my output:

```
keyword (9, 9)
key word (11, 12)
```

EDIT:

You may also add this

```
sentence = sentence.replace('[', ' [')
sentence = sentence.replace(']', '] ')
```

for avoiding possible errors when using split() and len() for counting word position